# Permanently configure Meteor development MongoDB url

Tags: meteor, nitrousio

I am trying a test to move all my development to Nitrous.io IDE, but with limited space in my Nitrous box I want to permanently host my Mongo databases at MongoHQ.com. Currently each day I need to set my MONGO_URL by running:

`export MONGO_URL='mongodb://<user>:<pass>@paulo.mongohq.com:12345/<db>'`

If I fire up another console or logout of Nitrous my MONGO_URL needs to set again.

How can I set the development MONGO_URL for good per meteor app? I cannot find a config file anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nitrous support helped me find a quick solution. Just wanted to answer it here for others with the same issue.

Open `~/.bash_profile` and enter your DB information.

example:

`export MONGO_URL='mongodb://jimmy:criket@paulo.mongohq.com:12345/mynitrobox'`

Next in the console run `source ~/.bash_profile` to load the settings.

This sets the DB for your entire node.js box, not individual meteor apps, so you may want to structure your Mongo collections accordingly with [subcollections](http://books.google.com/books?id=pAbSHFi4WSAC&lpg=PA7&ots=Dt7dOCk6t5&dq=subcollection&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q=Subcollection&f=false).

Comment: Not sure how Nitrous works but usually you would use a bash script that exports MONGO_URL and then runs meteor (probably using forever).  Then you run the bash script every time you need to start your server.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the guidance. Spotted a typo though, it should be "Open ~/.bash_profile", not bash-profile.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in one line like so:

```
MONGO_URL='mongodb://<user>:<pass>@paulo.mongohq.com:12345/<db>' meteor
```

I don't know much about Nitrous.io but in AWS EC2 I have an upstart job that runs this for me when the server starts.

I gist'd my approach a while back, I've since changed it a bit but this still works:

https://gist.github.com/davidworkman9/6466734

I don't know that this will help you in Nitrous.io though, good luck!

Comment: Thanks Dave. I did not even consider it being a Nitrous issue. They must have a script that runs whenever `meteor` is ran.